# How to avoid specifying full path in sudoers file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I am trying to add a `NOPASSWD` entry for `sudotest.sh` (or any script/binary that requires sudo) in my `/etc/sudoers` file (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server), but in order to make it work, I must specify the full path. The following entry works just fine:

```
%jenkins ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/home/vts_share/test/sudotest.sh
```

The problem is that the script might move to a different directory. This seems like a great chance to use the `*` wildcard in the path (i.e. `/*/sudotest.sh`) so that my script could be in any directory but the manual states that wildcards will not match the `/` character when used in a path. I've confirmed that it doesn't work.

I know that I can use the word `ALL` in place of my script, but this means there is no password prompt for any commands which seems unsafe.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Placing ALL instead of your script won't allow it to be run unless it can be found in a suitably configured PATH.

To run your command without supplying a full path it needs to be in a directory specified by the PATH variable.

For sudo it depends on how the environment is configured as to which PATH is used.

If the `secure_path` variable is set in sudoers then commands must be located in directories within it.

You can add users to the `exempt_group`, then they can use their own PATH.

Comment: From what manual did you learn this? Can you like a source for further detail.

Comment: That would be sudoers(8).