# Best practices to avoid Jenkins error: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, jenkins

When running any sudo command from Jenkins I get the following error:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

I understand that I can solve this by adding a `NOPASSWD` entry to my `/etc/sudoers` file which will allow user **jenkins** to run commands without needing a password. I can add an entry like this:

```
%jenkins ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/home/vts_share/test/sudotest.sh
```

...but this leads to the following issue: [how to avoid specifying full path in sudoers file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/520098/how-to-avoid-specifying-full-path-in-linux-sudoers-file)

I can add an entry like this:

```
%jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

...but this allows user **jenkins** to avoid the password prompt for all commands, which seems a bit unsafe. I'm just curious what my options are here, and if there are any best practices I should consider.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem(s) stem from not really understanding the tools that you are trying to work with. Now would be an opportune time to take a step back and learn some unix fundamentals and read up some on how sudo works.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for this option from `man sudoers`

```
   requiretty      If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in to a real tty.  When this flag     
                   is set, sudo can only be run from a login session and not via other means such as        
                   cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts.  This flag is off by default.
```

here are my recommendations in order of most secure to least secure:

1) don't let jenkins sudo at all. if you're doing package builds, look into `fakeroot`. jenkins doesn't need root to build software.

2) if you *do* need jenkins to have root, consider either restricting the sudo abilities with the sudoers `Cmnd` options.

3) run jenkins on a disposable VM. if someone roots it, rebuild it and re-evalutate your security choices. I would also recommend running jenkins as an intranet service, only accessible via LAN or VPN. don't forget to include authentication!

Answer (score 5):

if you run a sudo as a jenkins user as part of a script you need two things.

1. exact copy of the command..  like /bin/chown www-data /var/www
2. sudo -n exact command

the -n will tell it not to ask for a prompt if its a NOPASSWD.

this fixed me up for running sudo in a script that jenkins calls